# await async with Iron Python

Tags: c#, asynchronous

For now I was using Parallel methods to check urls for 200 status code, but this was slow method. Now I'm trying to move my code to await/async methods but it doesn't working

```
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            var timerPostingSpeed = new Timer(state =>
            {
                TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
                string postingSpeed = string.Format("{0:0}",
                                                   finishedUrls * 60 / (int)elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                UpdatingLabel(label1, postingSpeed);
            }, null, 5000, 10000);


            IEnumerable<string> urls = File.ReadLines("urls.txt");

            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

            var scriptSource =
                   engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"
                        if Open(__URL).Result:
                            print 1
                        ");

            await urls.ForEachAsync(20, async line =>
            {
                try
                {

                    var adderEngine = new SpeedEngine();
                  //  int zz = await adderEngine.Open(line);
                   // return;
                        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

                        scope.SetVariable("__URL", line);

                        scope.SetVariable("Open",
                            new Func<string, Task<int>>(adderEngine.Open));
                    try
                    {
                        await scriptSource.Execute(scope);
                    }
                    catch (UnboundNameException une)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(une.Message,
                            msg.
                                MySeoBoxForm_startPostingToolStripButton_Click_Unbound_Name_Error,
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    catch (SyntaxErrorException see)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            string.Format("{0}\nLine: {1}\nCode: {2}",
                                see.Message,
                                see.Line, see.GetCodeLine()),
                            msg.
                                MySeoBoxForm_startPostingToolStripButton_Click_Syntax_Error,
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    catch (MissingMemberException mme)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(mme.Message, "Missing Member",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentTypeException ate)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", ate.Message),
                            msg.
                                MySeoBoxForm_startPostingToolStripButton_Click_Syntax_Error,
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    catch (SystemExitException)
                    {

                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                {
                     MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", exc.Message),
                       msg.
                           MySeoBoxForm_startPostingToolStripButton_Click_Syntax_Error,
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                    finally
                    {

                     MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}","OK"),
                       msg.
                           MySeoBoxForm_startPostingToolStripButton_Click_Syntax_Error,
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                     MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", exc.Message),
                       msg.
                           MySeoBoxForm_startPostingToolStripButton_Click_Syntax_Error,
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                finally
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref finishedUrls);
                    numericUpDown1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        numericUpDown1.Value++;
                    }));
                }

            });
            timerPostingSpeed.Dispose();
        }

    }

   public async Task<int> Open(string siteUrl)
        {
                Uri newUri;
                if (!Uri.TryCreate(siteUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out newUri)) return 0;
                _uri = _openUri = newUri;
                _req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _uri);

                _response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(_req);

                if (_response == null || !_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                  return 0;
                }


                return 1;
        }
```

I need to use Iron Python - without it (when I uncomment *await adderEngine.Open(line); return;*) everything works ok. But with Iron Python my app stopped at *_response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(_req);* without errors. Also I noticed when I replace

```
await urls.ForEachAsync(20, async line =>
```

with:

```
await urls.ForEachAsync(1, async line =>
```

it's working

ForEachAsync: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx

Any help?

Comment: It doesn't help that you've got a bunch of empty catch blocks. I think it's highly likely that an exception is being thrown, and you're just swallowing it.

Comment: I have updated my questions - all catches have breakpoints

Answer (score 5):

If your Python code is calling `Task.Result`, and you're on a UI thread (as appears to be the case), [you can cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (I explain this fully on my blog). In short, the `async` method (`Open`) is trying to resume execution on the UI thread, but the UI thread is blocked by calling `Result`.

AFAIK, Python does not have `async`/`await` support, but you should be able to use `ContinueWith` (meh) or write some kind of bridge between `Task` and Twisted's `Deferred` (much cooler).

Comment: I must be missing something. What does this mean `Python does not have async/await support`? Does it have to? What is `async/await` support?  How is it related to c# code?

Comment: I've set *_response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(_req).ConfigureAwait(false);* and remove.Result from python code and now it's give me "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" exception

Comment: I mean Python does not have the `async` and `await` keywords or their equivalents. The ideal solution is to do the Python equivalent of `if await Open(__URL)` but that doesn't exist. So you should use `ContinueWith` or something like `Deferred`.